# Running multi-project sbt project results in clobbered compilation of shared project

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a play application and a normal scala application that have shared code in a dependency defined as such:

- project A
- project B
- shared

`lazy val shared = (project in file("shared")).settings(...)
    lazy val projectA = (project in file("A")).settings(...).dependsOn(shared)
    lazy val projectB = (project in file("B")).settings(...).dependsOn(shared)`

Due to the way sbt handles triggered execution, running `sbt ~run` in development mode is not usable for handling file changes correctly. I'm also using [sbt-revolver](https://github.com/spray/sbt-revolver) to handle re-running the non-play application. As a result, I run both applications separately using the commands:

```
sbt 'project A' '~run'
sbt 'project B' '~reStart'
```

in parallel, so when I make a change to `shared`, both try to recompile it, and therefore sometimes result in an error. I frankly despise SBT's documentation, and cannot figure out how to get this to work within SBT, so I am asking for help.

Comment: can you post the errors that you're getting ?

Comment: I don't think `sbt` supports this in a reliable way. I would not recommend it.